# QML Map.center trouble in QT5.7

Tags: qml, qt5.7

I try to upgrade Qt 5.6 project up to 5.7 and get some trouble with QML Map. I have a simple project with such code:

```js
Plugin {
    id: myPlugin
    name: "osm"
    PluginParameter {
        name: "osm.mapping.host";
        value: "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/"
    }
}

Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: myPlugin;
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(55.7512, 37.6175)
    zoomLevel: 12
    activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[6] //some magic to work
}
```

It works in 5.6 - I have all spots on map wich I define as `QtPositioning.coordinate()`. And it works in 5.7 too - with all my spots, except one thing - in 5.7 my map starts in the middle of Africa instead of coordinates I pointed at `Map.center`.

I tried running example from QtCreator - it had the same problem. So, I'd be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to set `Map.center` in 2 different ways:

**1.**

```js
Map {
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(55.7512, 37.6175)
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(map.center);
    }
}
```

The output was:

> qml: 0° 0' 0.0", 37° 37' 3.0" E

It looks that assigning coordinates in this way ignores latitude.

**2.**

```js
 Map {
    center {
        latitude: 55.7512
        longitude: 37.6175
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(map.center);
    }
}
```

The output was:

> qml: 55° 45' 4.3" N, 37° 37' 3.0" E

So assigning coordinates in this way works w/o problems.

As for me it looks like a bug. I've created a bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55424).